# delete records from related multiple EF tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I tried handle the cascading deletes manually deleting all of the related entities in the associated entity set

```
            try
            {
                using (var context = new Model1())
                {
                    var deleteEmp =
                        (from ed in context.EmployeeDept where ed.ID == edid select ed).FirstOrDefault();
                    foreach (EmployeeTask empTask in deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks)
                    {
                        context.EmployeeTasks.Remove(empTask);
                    }

                    context.EmployeeDepts.Remove(deleteEmp);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Existing employee could not be deleted " + ex.ToString());
            }
```

where ***edid*** is variable.
When I debugging by click F10 all executed correct until the line:
***context.EmployeeTasks.Remove(empTask);***
is executed and cursor returns back to ***in***.
After that I got error message:
*"System.Exception: 'Existing employee could not be deleted System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."*
What is a problem? How to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using cascade delete you can omit the loop. Otherwise use `context.EmployeeTasks.RemoveRange(deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks)` instead of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: How do you load `deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks`? Ef doesn't automatically load referenced properties

Comment: If you correctly load `deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks` in deleteEmp object, then you can just write: `deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks.Clear(); context.EmployeeDepts.Remove(deleteEmp);context.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: Hi Igor.
I tried to use your suggestion but got the same error.

Comment: Did you get it on the SaveChanges?

Comment: @Ярослав Виталиевич.
I substituted _**foreach**_ by code
`deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks.Clear();`
But got error message:
_The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable._
Or I did something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Really, my solution is only working if you have a cascade relationship. How are you loading `deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks`, with lazy load?

Comment: Show please your EmployeeTask class

Answer (score 0):

Add `.ToList()` after `deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks`

```cs
foreach (EmployeeTask empTask in deleteEmp.EmployeeTasks.ToList())
{
    context.EmployeeTasks.Remove(empTask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like this, but replace `i.parentId` for real navigation property

```
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Model1())
            {
                var deleteEmp = context.EmployeeDept.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == deletedEmpId);
                var childEmps = context.EmployeeDept.Where(i => i.parentId == deletedEmpId).ToList();

                context.EmployeeDepts.RemoveRange(childEmps);
                context.EmployeeDepts.Remove(deleteEmp);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Existing employee could not be deleted " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Cause of your problem

In Entity Framework you can only `Remove` items that are in the `DbContext.ChangeTracker`. Every item in the ChangeTracker has a State that says whether it is Added / Modified / Removed.

When you call SaveChanges, the ChangeTracker is checked to see which items must be updated.

Whenever you fetch a complete items, so without using `Select`, the item is automatically stored in the ChangeTracker. There are other methods to add items to the change tracker, but those are out of scope of this question.

So all you need to do, is fetch all items that you want to Remove, before you remove them.

### The solution

So you have `Employees` and `EmployeeTasks`. Apparently there is a one-to-many relation between `Employees` and `EmployeeTasks`: every `Employee` has zero or more `EmployeeTasks`; every `EmployeeTask` belongs to exactly one `Employee`, namely the `Employee` that the foreign key `EmployeeId` refers to.

You need to fetch the Employee and all EmployeeTasks, remove all tasks, and then remove the Employee:

```
int employeeToRemoveId = ...
using (var dbContext = new EmployeeDbContext(...))
{
    var employee = dbContext.Employees.Find(employeeToRemoveId);
    if (employee != null)
    {
        // there is an employee with this Id. get its tasks:
        var tasksOfThisEmployee = dbContext.EmployeeTasks
            .Where(task=> task.EmployeeId == employeeToRemoveId)
            .ToList();

        // remove the tasks; remove the employee; save the changes
        dbContext.EmployeeTasks.RemoveRange(tasksOfThisEmployee);
        dbContext.Employees.Remove(employee);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    // else: there is no Employee with this Id; nothing to do.
}
```

Simple comme bonjour!